# Is it possible to test an HttpSessionListener with Spring-MVC and Spring-Test-MVC?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, servlets, servlet-listeners

We have some logic in an `HttpSessionListener` that we'd like to test. We're using Spring MVC and the associated testing framework, with `MockMvc` and so on. Unfortunately, we haven't found a way to get the listener initialized so that when a session is created or destroyed the appropriate listener methods are called.

I have tried to add the listener programmatically rather than using `web.xml` (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433321/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-httpsessionlistener-using-spring)) and this works fine when running in a Servlet 3.0 container. But when running with Spring Test it all goes wrong, as the `MockServletContext` [does not support the `addListener` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext.html), and so throws an exception.

Is there any way to test such listeners without using integration testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Servlet container decides when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452757/httpsessionlistener-will-sessiondestroyed-method-be-called-on-session-timeout) to dispatch events to the `HttpSessionListener`. This is not necessarily right after a session created or destroyed. Because this depends on the container implementation, you can't depend on the unit test. Integration testing is the way to go.

You can always unit test those [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) implementations

```
HttpSessionListener listener = new MyHttpSessionListener();
listener.sessionCreated(mockEvent);
listener.sessionDestroyed(mockEvent);
```

outside the context of your application.

Comment: I would assume that the events are dispatched soon enough after the session is actually created or invalidated. The assumption in the unit test is that the session events _are_ triggered - the _when_ is less important. But your point is taken.

Comment: @WillHarris You should not be testing something like `request.getSession().invalidate()` triggering an event (it's a well known and tested framework, it will work). You should be testing if that call is actually executed.